# Insert blank row if dates don't match google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to find a way to insert blank rows in google sheets if a script detects a difference in dates. On the surface it seems simple, but I have been trying to find a solution for days.

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
Month   Brand   Size    Impressions
2017/1  Nike    300x25  500
2017/1  Nike    300x250 300
2017/2  Nike    728x90  100
2017/2  Adidas  300x250 400
```

What I need to happen is that when the script detects the change between 2017/1 and 2017/2 it will insert two blank rows so that the months are separated.

Like this:

```
Month   Brand   Size    Impressions
2017/1  Nike    300x25  500
2017/1  Nike    300x250 300


2017/2  Nike    728x90  100
2017/2  Adidas  300x250 400
```

Obviously this could be done manually, but the sheet is dynamically populated from DFP and is meant to be an automated report.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Changes Into Spaces

I lucked out ran first time. I actually formatted the date column in the year month format to make sure the getMonth() function would work.

```
function spacesIntoChanges() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var rg=sh.getDataRange();
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var spaces=[];
    for(var i=2;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      if(vA[i][0] && vA[i-1][0] && new Date(vA[i][0]).getMonth() != new Date(vA[i-1][0]).getMonth())//
      {
        spaces.push(i);
      }
    }
    spaces.sort(compareNumbers);
    for(var i=vA.length-1;i>=2;i--)
    {
      if(spaces.indexOf(i)>-1)
      {
        sh.insertRows(Number(i+1), 2);
      }
    }
}


function compareNumbers(a,b)
{
  return b-a;
}
```

Sheet before execution:

[image]

Sheet after execution:

[image]

Added some more unspaced rows:

[image]

Then executed again:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This helps so much.

Comment: When I run the script though it adds 2 lines after every month, not just when the change is detected. 

I noticed in my sample I had a typo where I put the dates as 2017/1 when in the work file its actually 2017|1

I've tried to do an automatic replace on that character but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Yes my script is looking for changes in the month because it looked like that's what you were after.  So what are you after?

Comment: So do you just want to detect changes in a string?

Comment: We are actually looking for a month but the way DFP formats the output the add a pipe instead of a forward slash. I tried reformatting it to the way you're querying for but it didn't seem to have an affect.

Comment: Nevermind! I messed up my order of operations. I was able to replace the | and as soon as I did, everything worked perfect!!

Comment: @K.Smith I'd appreciate it if you would check off my answer.  Thanks